# Phonegap form processing error

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql, cordova

I am making an android app in phonegap using the following code to insert the data from phonegap to the mysql database. I couldn't figure out where is an error in my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's script -->
    <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ionicNFC" ng-controller="MainController">

<ion-pane>
    <ion-content>
        <div ng-if="!tag.id">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="item item-text-wrap center">
                    <img src="img/nfc_load.gif">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="tag.id">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                    <div class="card" ng-repeat="record in tag.ndefMessage">
                        <div class="item item-divider">
<button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="clear()" ng-if="tag.id">Clear</button>

                        </div>
                        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                        <form method="post" id="myForm">
                        <input type="text" name="data" id="record.id" value="" placeholder="data"  />
                        <button type="submit">Save</button> 
                        </form>
                            <!-- <dl>
                                <dd>{{ record.type | bytesToString }}</dd>
                                <dt ng-if="record.id">Record Id</dt>
                                <dd ng-if="record.id">{{ record.id | bytesToString }}</dd>
                                <dd>{{ record | decodePayload }}</dd>

                            </dl> -->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

In above html code I want to save this data:

```
<dl>
<dd>{{ record.type | bytesToString }}</dd>
<dt ng-if="record.id">Record Id</dt>
<dd ng-if="record.id">{{ record.id | bytesToString }}</dd>
<dd>{{ record | decodePayload }}</dd>                               
</dl>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
 $('#myForm').submit(function() {

    var postTo = 'http://192.168.1.5/phonegap/data/store_data.php';

    $.post(postTo,({tag_data: $('[name=tag_data]').val()}),
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
        if(data != "") {
            // do something
        } else {
            // couldn't connect
        }
        },'json');
    return false;

});
```

Comment: What happens when you use this code? What would you like to happen?

Comment: Nothing happens. The above code is Phonegap NFC reader (https://github.com/don/ionic-nfc-reader). I am trying to send the retrieved NFC tag information to the mysql database.